# Display in node custom field profile

Tags: 7, theming

I created a custom field in the users profiles.

I need to display in node.tpl.php, this field for the author of the node.

I tried :

```
<?php 
print $node_author = user_load($node->uid); 
print ($node_author->field_custom); 
?>
```

But i have an error :

```
Recoverable fatal error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Do you know where I'm wrong? 
And, is it the best way of proceeding?

Comment: print $node_author = user_load($node->uid);  in this use nid  $node is represnted  in nid or use $profile

Comment: $node->uid = $user->uid;

Answer (score 0):

Try with `print render($node_author->field_custom);`

Or you can try as well:

insert at the top of you node.tpl.php

```
<?php 
global $user;
$node_author = user_load($user->uid);
$yourvariable = $node_author->field_custom;
?>
```

Where you want print the field insert:

```
<?php print $yourvariable['und'][0]['value'];?>
```

Comment: It does not work. I have an error: `Recoverable fatal error : Object of class stdClass`

Comment: Mmmm...try: `print $node_author->field_custom['und'][0]['value']`

Comment: Does'nt work too ;) error : `Notice : Undefined index: und dans include()`

Comment: @Fluidouix I have update my answer. Try.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the above code with below one:

```
<?php 
  $node_author = user_load($node->uid); 
  print ($node_author->field_custom); 
?>
```

Comment: It does not work.Error :  `Notice : Array to string conversion in include()...`

Answer (score 0):

You are using print when assigning into a variable, that's you are getting error.

remove print from line 2 and the code should be  as below

```
<?php 
$node_author = user_load($node->uid); 
print render($node_author->field_custom); 
?>
```

Comment: It does not work.Error :  `Notice : Array to string conversion in include()...`

Comment: Ca`n you please provide what print_r($node_author); output.

Comment: a big line wich i cut a little and who start with : `stdClass Object ( [uid] => 3 [name] => name [pass] => (...) [mail] => name@gmail.com [theme] => [signature] => [signature_format] => filtered_html [created] => (...) [access] => (...) [login] => (...) [status] => 1 [timezone] => Europe [language] => fr [picture] => [init] => name@gmail.com [data] => Array ( [ckeditor_default] => t [ckeditor_show_toggle] => t [ckeditor_width] => 100% [ckeditor_lang] => en [ckeditor_auto_lang] => t ) [roles] => Array ( [2] => authenticated user [4] => (....)`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in the way you are printing the value. actually `print` is just used for printing string, while `print_r` is used for printing array or Object. so in your case when you use `$node_author->field_custom`, then as it is an array, therefore it is not printing and giving you error. You can print it as below.

```
print_r($node_author->field_custom);
```

It will print the array, and will not give you error, however if you just want to print the value, then you can print somewhat like:

```
print $node_author->field_custom[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

If above code doesnot work, then paste output of

```
print_r($node_author->field_custom);
```

It will give better approach.

//Edited

```
$image_url = file_create_url($node_author->field_custom[und][0]['uri']);
print render(theme_image($image_url));
```

Or

```
print render($node_author->field_custom);
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj for this detailed answer, I tried your various solutions, but all return me an error, `Recoverable fatal error` or `Notice : Undefined index: value in include()`

Comment: dont use print $node_author->field_custom[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; 

Just use print_r($node_author->field_custom);, after that I will be able to give the answer.

Comment: It returns me : `Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 17 [uid] => 1 [filename] => name.jpg [uri] => public://name.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => (...) [status] => 1 [timestamp] => (...) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( ) [alt] => [title] => [width] => 199 [height] => 300 ) ) ) `